# How can I ffill a datframe nan values from a diffrent dataframe with limit?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I am trying to ffill a dataframe with a limit of 2 and values from another dataframe. However when running the following code `DF1.fillna(value=DF2,method='ffill',axis=0,limit=2)`, I get this error `ValueError: Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.` DF1 and DF2 are identical in shape, columns and index.

DF1

| CompanyId | 1/1/2018 | 1/1/2019 | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | nan | nan |
| 2 | 12 | 16 | nan | 12 |
| 3 | 14 | 17 | nan | 13 |
| 4 | nan | 18 | 12 | 14 |
| 5 | nan | 18 | 13 | nan |
| 6 | nan | nan | 14 | nan |

DF2

| CompanyId | 1/1/2018 | 1/1/2019 | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 31 | 41 | 51 |
| 2 | 22 | 32 | 42 | 52 |
| 3 | 23 | 33 | 43 | 53 |
| 4 | 24 | 34 | 44 | 54 |
| 5 | 25 | 35 | 45 | 55 |
| 6 | 26 | 36 | 46 | 56 |

Expected result

| CompanyId | 1/1/2018 | 1/1/2019 | 1/1/2020 | 1/1/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | nan | nan |
| 2 | 12 | 16 | nan | 12 |
| 3 | 14 | 17 | nan | 13 |
| 4 | **24** | 18 | 12 | 14 |
| 5 | **25** | 18 | 13 | **55** |
| 6 | nan | **36** | 14 | **56** |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` have the identical index and columns, here is one way to approach the problem:

Forward fill `df1` with `limit=2`, then use `isna` to create a boolean mask. Now, use this boolean mask to `mask` the values in `df2`, finally fill the nan values in `df1` using the masked dataframe `df2`

```
df1.fillna(df2.mask(df1.ffill(limit=2).isna()))
```

---

```
   CompanyId  1/1/2018  1/1/2019  1/1/2020  1/1/2021
0          1      10.0      15.0       NaN       NaN
1          2      12.0      16.0       NaN      12.0
2          3      14.0      17.0       NaN      13.0
3          4      24.0      18.0      12.0      14.0
4          5      25.0      18.0      13.0      55.0
5          6       NaN      36.0      14.0      56.0
```